# what is the meaning of : ${CONTAINER_CLI:="docker"} in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, automation, parameter-expansion

I am learning shell scripting and came across this line

```
: ${CONTAINER_CLI:="docker"}
```

can someone please explain me what this line do? what is the meaning of : here?

Answer (score 0):

`man bash` command said:

```
${parameter:=word}
```

> Assign Default Values.
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is
> assigned to parameter.
> The value of parameter is then substituted.
> Positional parameters and special parameters
> may not be assigned to in this way.

So, the variable `CONTAINER_CLI` is assigned with the value `docker` if `CONTAINER_CLI` does not exists or empty.

But... if you simply write :

```
${CONTAINER_CLI:="docker"}
```

You obtain an error if the result is not a command.
You just want make a assignation.
Put simply a `:` before.

It's like:

```
CONTAINER_CLI=${CONTAINER_CLI:="docker"}
```